# Output results from the javascript array(Ajax?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a piece of code which I would like to append results from the employees array into the output div. There is a keyup function, and what I'm trying to accomplish is to print the results in list without reloading the page. Is there any better way perhaps, maybe with some autocomplete plugin? Is the ajax call necessary at all..?

Here's my codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwjGxr and code:

```
<input type="text" id="search"/>
<div id="output"></div>

var employees = ["John Doe", "Anna Smith", "Peter Jones", "Cat Stevens", "Dog Whishers"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').keyup(function() {
    var searchTerm = $('#search').val();
    var url = searchTerm;

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url,
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        $('#output').html('');
        for (var i = 0; i < employees.length; i++) {
          $('#output').append("<li> [i] </li>");

        }
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: `"<li>" + employees[i] + "</li>"` - and there's no need for the ajax call since you apparently don't use the results anyway.

Comment: Oh thank you..now when I type any name that's inside the array all the results appear immediately. Is there a way to "fill" the results based on how many letters that are typed into an input field, for example if i type John that only John appears..? Here's my updated code: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gwjGxr?editors=1010   @Pointy

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://jsfiddle.net/sqs53ned/

Comment: Perfect, thank you @Artur

Comment: Works great here, but I get Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. That's in Firefox no matter what jquery version I connect..? In chrome I get  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///echo/html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. @Artur Filipiak

Comment: it seems to work only on jsfiddle..Codepen and locally in browser i get those errors..

Comment: `echo/html` is a *dummy url* (for JSFiddle demo only). You should put yur own `url` in AJAX request.

Comment: `getPreventDefault()` is not related to this question.

Comment: sorry, that's the error I get anywhere except jsfiddle, so I'm now looking for a solution @ArturFilipiak